# Facebook Tracking Pixel: Can't create a Custom Coversion based on a custom event

Tags: javascript, facebook

In the official **[FB guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/api-reference#events)** I've read that, apart from standard events, I can also use custom ones. It's perfect, actually, as I'm trying to create a Custom Conversion using a custom event.

In the guide, the following code is presented for a custom event:

```
// Custom event (can be used for audience building and custom conversions)
fbq('trackCustom', 'MyCustomEvent', {custom_param: 'custom_value'});
```

Note, that the comment says *"and custom conversions"*.

So, somewhere in my JS, I have a snippet reacting on click:

```
$('#elem').on('click', function() {
    fbq('trackCustom', 'MyEvent');
});
```

Unfortunately, when I try to create a new Custom Conversion and I use the new, custom event name, the "Next" button is inactive:

[image]

Additionally, the only Events I can choose, are the standard ones, and only the ones I actually track (or tracked) on page load:

[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Should the custom event be somehow "registered" first before it is available for Custom Conversion?

Otherwise, I don't understand why the documentation tells me I can do something that I can't.

Any insights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To anyone with the same problem: turns out, the missing factor was time.

After a custom event is triggered once, it will be detected and displayed in the Pixel events list. It will also be available when a Custom Conversion is being created. In my case it took about 30 min until I saw the custom event tracked.

As simple as that. Wish this info was provided clearly, anywhere in the docs.